# Display format of the time in the status bar

Tags: ios, uistatusbar

A customer has sent me an email about a bug in one of my apps that I am trying to figure out. The bug has to do with time, and I am unable to recreate it. (Also my app has been out many months and I haven't had any other report of this bug). I noticed in a screenshot that the customer sent that in his status bar, the time is displayed like this:

03:34 PM

instead of like this:

3:34 PM

My question is how can I get my status bar to display time like in the first case, so I can see if this has anything to do with my bug. My customer is using iOS 5.1 on an iPhone 3GS.

Comment: Hm, it's probably a locale setting. Where is your customer located? I'd get them to take screen shots of the settings app in General->Date & Time and General->International and try to mimic those on your device.

Comment: Yes you're right. It's General->International->Region Format (and then there are a number of region formats that will produce this effect). I figured it out but couldn't post an answer to my question yet. Feel free to post the answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually these types of issues arise from differences in the locale and time formats between them. Get your customer to take screen shots of the settings app, in particular General->International and General->Date & Time and mimc those settings on your own device and see if that helps.